# "can't modify frozen string" when running gem on file $RUBY_HOME/rubygems/version.rb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I compiled ruby 1.9.3-p134 from source on RedHat RHEL 5.2.

Everything went smoothly except two things.

**1**
When trying to run ruby from the command line it said not found in /usr/bin/ruby, but `which ruby` pointed to `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. So i created a softlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`, however ...

**2**
gem gives me the following error:

`$ gem`

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb:191:in `strip!': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb:191:in `initialize'
       from /usr/bin/gem:14:in `new'
       from /usr/bin/gem:14:in `<main>'
```

No luck googling since "can't modify frozen String" is a common ruby error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I might have had conflicting gem installs.

`find / -name gem 2>/dev/null`

```
/home/muradan/install_ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.6/bin/gem
/usr/share/locale/gem
/usr/bin/gem        <----- which gem, doesn't work
/usr/local/bin/gem  <----- works
```

So I deleted and softlinked it to /usr/local/bin/gem.

Now I got problems with other gem stuff like gemlocks (which doesn't exist in /usr/local/bin or anywhere else except the non working /usr/bin)

UGH!! Why isn't linux consistent! what's the point of application installing to /usr/bin and some to /usr/local/bin with no rhyme or reason! 
FML